# Difference between events close and disconnect Socket I/O

Tags: sockets, socket.io

On server side there are two events namely `close` and `disconnect`. What is the difference between the two. How and when are they fired respectively. Here is the [doc](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io) on socket.io

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){
  client.on('disconnect', function(){
     ///
  });

  client.on('close', function(){///});
}
```